# How to properly retrieve information from an AXI4-Stream interface?

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, ethernet, axi4

I have got a module with an *AXI4-Stream* interface. I want this module to extract an ethernet frame from the incoming `TDATA` signal in order to change  some of its fields and send it forward to the output.

The issue is that the frame is bigger than the `TDATA` signal (512 bits vs 64 bits), so if, for instance, I were to parse the *source MAC address* field (which is 48-bits wide), it would be sent over two different `TDATA` chunks. This, at least with my experience in design, makes the parsing logic more difficult. Because of this, I was wondering what could be the most efficient/correct way to do it retrieve data from `TDATA`. I was thinking in storing the 64-bit chunks within a 512-bit word FIFO queue and parse such word more easily, but as I am not very experience in digital design, I'm not sure if this could be troublesome in any way.

I have tried to look information on the topic but I could not find any, so I would appreciate if anyone could help me by indicating if my FIFO idea makes sense at all or what would be the correct way to do it.